# jQuery: is element.click(func) or element.attr('onclick','func()') more efficient?

Tags: javascript, onclick, jquery

I'm populating a list by cloning elements into it. Then I change attrs to make each item unique. They need to call a function on click, so I'm wondering if it's more efficient to use `new_element.click(func);` or `new_element.attr('onlick','func();');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new_element.attr('onclick','func();');
```

Is:

- inefficient (needlessly creating a new inline function from a string, that does nothing except call func and lose the `this` reference);
- aggravating to put any complex code in, since it all has to be JS string escaped;
- broken in IE, due to bugs in `setAttribute`.

Avoid. `click()`/`bind('click')` is there for a reason.

Comment: And it's prone to typos (`onclikc`)

Answer (score 3):

onclick has a number of limitations, including cluttering the DOM and only allowing one function at a time.  So you should use click.  See [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Directly referencing the function will be more efficient than having to interpret a string.

The lowest touch way of doing this, however, is this way:

```
$(links_selector).live('click', func);
```

`links_selector` will presumably be something like `ul.listClass a.actionClass`. This will not require anything to be done when new list elements get added.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery then make it this way

```
new_element.click(function(){
    // your code
});
```

or you can bind the click event handler like

```
new_element.bind("click", function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the function already exists and is called from a few places. An anonymous function would not be appropriate for me.

Answer (score 0):

Any difference in performance between the two is most likely going to be negligible. You should use the one that reads better, and that's `element.click`. (Plus, `onclick` has many disadvantages, as @Matthew Flaschen mentioned.)