# jQuery change document.location.href in input

Tags: jquery

is it possible to use jQuery to do that:

if the body has a `<div id="wpadminbar">`
then change the  document.location.href in this input from

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href='/wp-login.php?action=register';" value="Forum" id="forum">
```

to

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href='/forum';" value="Forum" id="forum">
```

Comment: on an unrelated side note, you can omit href altogether. just use `document.location="blah_blah.html"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if($('#wpadminbar').length > 0) {
    $('#forum').attr('onClick', "document.location.href='/forum';");
}
```

Comment: Another way to check for that adminbar div would be to use the :has selector: if ($('body:has("#wpadminbar")))

Comment: @Jody: `.has('#wpadminbar')` will return true if the body contains an element with id "wpadminbar", but will not match a body who's ID is "wpadminbar."

Comment: @George: The question asks about a body that contains a div with that id.

Comment: @Jody `.length` is the de-facto null checker. see jquery [FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/FAQ). @Neal: `$('#myDiv').length` would do. you could omit `>0` as zero is `falsy` :)

Answer (score 5):

You may want to do this in Javascript alone. Instead of changing the links there, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).load(function() {
  $("#forum").click(function() {
   document.location.href="your URL";
  });
 });
</script>
```

If you can, place that in your `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery("#forum").attr("onclick", "document.location.href='/forum'");
```

Comment: Forgive the typo, I missed the hash mark. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @naveen, its the same thing that I did. give me `-1` as well?

Comment: Okay @naveen you are going to have to explain your reasoning for the -1. It works just fine.

Comment: @brenjit: taken back the -1. because its not the answer at all. you haven't bothered at all about `wpadminbar` @Neal: since you asked. I didn't give you a -1 or a +1. the -1 thought did cross my mind though :) because 1. `onClick` should be `onclick`  2. never use `attr('onclick')` you have `.click(function(){` and `.bind("click", function(){` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734848/jquery-is-element-clickfunc-or-element-attronclick-func-more-efficient